# Кроссплатформенная сбока QT на Linux

Tags: linux, qt, gcc, кросс-компиляция

Здравствуйте.
Мне нужно собрать QT на Linux машине для другой Linux машины. Архитектура одна и та же x86_64. Я собрал кросс-компилятор crosstool-ng и попробовал с помощью него собрать QT из исходиков. При вызове configure я указал следующие параметры:

```
../qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.8.0/configure \
    -opensource \
    -no-opengl \
    -debug \
    -static \
    -no-dbus \
    -syslog \
    -linuxfb \
    -evdev \
    -nomake examples \
    -sysroot /opt/work/cross-build/rootfs \
    -platform linux-g++-64 \
    -xplatform linux-g++ \
    -device-option CROSS_COMPILE=/home/oleg/x-tools/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu- \
    -v
```

/home/oleg/x-tools/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu- - это путь к моему кросс-компилятору.
/opt/work/cross-build/rootfs - это путь к корневой файловой системой с установленной Linux.
Сборка прошла, однако она произвелась неверно: для сборки QT использовал компилятор g++, а не указанный кросс-компилятор x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-g++. Просмотрев файлы qtbase/mkspec/linux-g++/qmake.conf, я увидел, что так и должно быть. В этом файле нет указаний использовать ${CROSS_COMPILE}g++.
Как тогда собрать QT?

Comment: Если у Вас одна и таже архитектура, то зачем тогда кросскомпилятор?

Comment: А что, prebuilt Qt для Linux нет?

Comment: @KoVadim Мне казалось, это необходимо. На целевой системе нет многих библиотек и их версии другие. Скажем другая libc, там процессор другой, более старый(почему я и не хочу собирать на ней, это займет очень много времени). На целевой платформе не установлен X сервер.

Comment: @Rou1997 Мне нужно, чтобы QT работал через LinuxFB. Prebuild может работать только через X-сервер.

Comment: @OlegGavrilchenko Кому нужно, пусть поставят иксы и не насилуют мозг.

Comment: @OlegGavrilchenko, самый лучший способ -- установить другую систему со сборочным окружением в chroot. Это вас избавить от головняка. Если коротко, просто сделайте дамп рабочих каталогов диска к себе на компьютер в какой-нибудь каталог, потом делайте туда `chroot /path/to/my/local/copy/of/the/target/system`. Подробнее гуглите по тегу `chroot`.

Comment: @eri, libc -- тут никак буквы **к** нет. И читается она **[lib c]**.

Comment: пусть будет либц. с остальными либами выходит просто положить их в папку с екзешником, а либц так работать отказывается.

может есть какой варианти перелинковать всё статикой?